# wp_nav_menu does not take arguments?

Tags: menus

I am sorry for this nooby question, but I just don't get it :

I was working with the function reference for wp_nav_menu and this is my line of code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'header-menu','items_wrap' => '%3$s') ); ?>
```

But the menu is displayed in `<ul><li>` anyway. (I want to remove that and make the menu horizontal).
I can put anything in the `items_wrap`, it will always be the default `<ul>`
The theme_location is maybe not working too, but since I have only one menu yet, it displays the right one.

I want to say sorry again if this is very stupid, which I guess it is, but I ask for your patience and help, just a beginner here.

Full index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(isset($_GET['nav'])) {
$nav = $_GET['nav']; } ?>
<body>

<div id="topbar">
    <div id="orangebar"></div>
    <div id="top-middle">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img id="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png" /></a>
        <div id="menu">
<?php
remove_all_actions( 'wp_nav_menu_args' );
remove_all_actions( 'wp_nav_menu' );

echo "\n\n<!-- start menu -->\n";
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'items_wrap' => 'j' ) );
echo "\n<!-- end menu -->\n\n";
?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="center">
    <div id="centershade"><img id="shade" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/shade.png" /></div>
    <div id="main">

        <a href="facebook link" target="_blank"><img id="fbbutton" src="    <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/buttons/fb.gif" /></a>
        <a href="twitter link" target="_blank"><img id="twitbutton" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/buttons/twitter.gif" /></a>

        <div id="main-content">
            <?php if (!( isset($nav) ) ) { include('startpage.php');} else { include($nav+'.php');} ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

functions.php:

```
<?php add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'header-menu', __( 'Header Menu' ) );
}

?>
```

Ok, please try to get over unstandardized naming and strange ways of achieving stuff, this is one-third learning, one-third testing and one-third development..

Comment: Unordered lists can be styled vertically or [horizontally](https://www.google.com/search?q=unordered+lists+horizontal).

Comment: Well yes, but anyways this thing is still a problem. If the "theme_location" does not work, it will be a big problem when I add another menu. And "items_wrap" is more powerful than just removing ul...

Comment: The code you are using above works on my web site. The `<ul></ul>` tags are removed. The list items are still wrapped in `<li></li>` tags. The documentation does not indicate that the `items_wrap` argument will remove the `<li></li>` tags. Your conclusion that the `theme_location` argument "maybe not working too" is only a guess until you actually test your conclusion.

Comment: On my server, the '<ul>' is not removed. I did not test with adding new menus, but I did try adding an '$after' string and of course, it did not work. Well this is a problem already.

Comment: That is perplexing. Try adding more code near the menu PHP code you provided above. Something like `echo '<!-- menu started -->';` before and `echo '<!-- menu ended -->';` after, then check the browser page source to see if the `<ul></ul>` tags are inside those comments or outside them.

Comment: That is an interesting tip. But, there is a <div> containing an <ul> containing the <li> menu items inbetween the comments, just like it should be.

Comment: If you remove the `items_wrap` argument, and just use `array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' )`, are there 2 sets of `<ul></ul>` tags inside the comments?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' )`. I'm using `primary` to test on my web server.

Comment: Only one set. --

edit: Well it does the same with primary as with header-menu, so no problem there :D

Answer (score 1):

The `items_wrap` argument is in fact a `sprintf`-ed argument.

When you look into [Core source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L151):

```
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
```

...you see that you have to use the [arguments to let core do its work](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L246).

```
sprintf( $args->items_wrap, esc_attr( $wrap_id ), esc_attr( $wrap_class ), $items );
```

Here're the `%`-arguments:

- `%1$s` -> `$wrap_id`
- `%2$s` -> `$wrap_class`
- `%3$s` -> `$items`

Now to replace the container, you'll need to use for e.g. something like the following:

```
'items_wrap' => '<div id="1%$s" class="%s$s">%3$s</div>'
```

Keep in mind that this *is not* the container. The container itself is only allowed to be a `div` or `nav` element. But you can extend the list of allowed container elements:

```
$allowed_tags = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', array( 'div', 'nav' ) );
```

Comment: Yes, I know. When I set `'items_wrap'` to `' '`, it should not print the menu items at all. But it does, as if it did not even consider the argument.

Comment: IIRC you can't drop blank values in. Internally PHP should overwrite empty statements as `wp_parse_args()` basically is a prepare-wrapper for `array_merge()`. Maybe you can use `&nbsp;`, but I doubt that it will prove useful. Try replacing it with _any_ char or string first.

Comment: That is a good point, but the results are still the same. ( I set items_wrap to 'j' )

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried, what the output/result was and where it's failing. Thing get slightly confused, spread and lost in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting too long for comments. Try debugging with this in place of the code you originally posted in your question:

```
<?php
remove_all_actions( 'wp_nav_menu_args' );
remove_all_actions( 'wp_nav_menu' );

echo "\n\n<!-- start menu -->\n";
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) );
echo "\n<!-- end menu -->\n\n";
?>
```

Check the browser page source for the `<ul></ul>` tags.

This should test to see if anything is overriding the menu arguments or menu output through PHP using a filter. The extra newlines (`\n`) I placed in the echo statements should make the menu easier to locate in the browser page source.

---

> Well, still the same result: comment > div > ul > li ...

Weird. What is the full markup that appears starting with the `<!-- start menu -->` comment. With the `items_wrap` argument removed, on my server this follows:

```
<!-- start menu -->
<div class="menu-primary-container"><ul id="menu-primary-1" class="menu">
```

BTW, you can add code and markup to a comment by adding a backtick ` before and after it. On my keyboard, the backtick key is left of the numeral 1 key.

Comment: Well, still the same result:

comment > div > ul > li

Comment: See the edit for more test code.

Comment: I just discovered that on a slovak keyboard layout, I can write it with Shift+Alt Gr+ 7 twice. 


`<!-- start menu -->
<div class="menu"><ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-25">
link content
</li>
a few more list items
</ul></div>

<!-- end menu -->`

Comment: Are you running a plugin or JavaScript code that automatically corrects invalid HTML?

Comment: I use no plugin at all, nor did I add any JS to my theme/design yet.

Comment: Where is the code run? For example, is it in a widget or in a file? If it is in a file, which file is it?

Comment: index.php of a theme

Comment: We probably need to see all the code so we can try to test your `index.php` template file. Can you [add (to your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/115212/edit)) all the code in that file and in your theme `functions.php` file so we can test your code locally?

Comment: Added index and functions